# Deleting post with React Redux API delete request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api, thunk

When I console log `this.props` I get an array with `post.id` and I want to make `onClick` function to remove this item from the list and do not show on the page.
What is wrong with my code there?

So this is what I have:

````js
export const deletePost = id => dispatch => {
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
    method: "DELETE"
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(post =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_POST,
        payload: id
      }),
    );
};

my reducer:

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  item: {}
};
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      };
    case DELETE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      };

Component contains of

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.postsReducer.items,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchPosts, deletePost
}

And Delete button on each post:

<button key={post.id} onClick={()=>this.props.deletePost()}>X</button>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing a couple of things here that you should take a look at, and hopefully they'll help you to solve your issue.

First of all, **note that your `deletePost` function expects a parameter** with the post id. However, in the JSX code you posted for your button, you're not passing any value to the function at all. This means that the property `payload` will have an `undefined` value by the time the action is dispatched.

Make sure you update your view to pass it an id, so you call the proper endpoint (your `DELETE` request is probably pointing to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/undefined` right now) and the reducer actually receives the id of the post you want to remove:

```
<button key={post.id} onClick={()=>this.props.deletePost(post.id)}>X</button>
```

The second thing you have to check is the implementation of your reducer. From what I've understood in your message and the code for the `deletePost` method, `action.payload` should contain a number.

That being the case, how your reducer is handling the `DELETE_POST` action in the reducer doesn't make too much sense to me.

```
case DELETE_POST:
    return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
    };
```

Reducers are supposed to be pure functions that, for a given state and action, returns an entirely new state based on the action it receives. Remember too that the state you receive cannot be altered at all: if the original instance is mutated in any way, your code will not work.

In this case, you need to return a new state where your `items` property is replaced by a new list where the id you want to remove is missing. In the piece of code you wrote, however, **you're replacing the `items` array by a number**. This is not what was supposed to happen, starting by the fact that `items` should still be an array of numbers.

What you actually need to do is to **create a new array that does not include the item you wanted to remove**. You may use the [`filter`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) method to achieve this:

```
case DELETE_POST:
    return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
    };
```

This code should do exactly what you want: here we are assigning the `items` property in your state an entirely new array where the deleted post is not included.

`filter` returns an array with the items for which the specified function returns `true`. In this case, the arrow function we're passing to `filter` returns `true` for every item that's different from the id of the post you want to remove.

By using this method you will also have no problems with the initial `state.items` value being mutated somehow, as `filter` returns a new instance of `Array` and does not alter the original.